# Why are the outputs of printf and std::cout different?

Tags: c++

I tried the following code of C++. However, the outputs of `printf` and `std::cout` are different. Why?

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", &Foo::c);  // The output is 8
    std::cout << &Foo::c << "\n"; // The output is 1
}
```

Comment: `main.cpp:22:27: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int Foo::*’ [-Wformat=]`

Comment: @Angew -- I was replying to a comment that has now been deleted. It said that `Foo::c` hadn't been initialized.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`printf("%d\n", &Foo::c)`: this is undefined behavior, as `&Foo::c` is not an integer, but a pointer to member (but, actually, it is usual that the compiler stores pointer to data member as offset, and as `8` is the offset of `Foo::c`, `8` is printed).

`std::cout << &Foo::c`: this prints the value `&Foo::c`. As iostream doesn't have a pointer to member printer, it chooses the closest one: it converts it to `bool`, and prints it as integer. As `&Foo::c` converted to `bool` is `true`, `1` is printed.

Comment: You know member-pointers have to take into account the possibility of virtual inheritance?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Only for classes that use virtual inheritance, of course. There's no member pointer equivalent of `void*`, each class has its own unique types of member pointers. Even `sizeof(int Foo::*)` may depend on `Foo`.

Comment: @MSalters No. You can have and use a `int Foo::*` perfectly fine while `Foo` is still incomplete and in no danger of being completed anytime soon. Admittedly, MS especially likes to play fast and loose with member-pointers of any kind.

Comment: @all - I held my peace until now, but can we stop with the "member-pointer" business? The term is "pointer-to-member". And when it comes to technical terms, it matters. Just as "chocolate milk" isn't the same as "milk chocolate". </pedantry>

Comment: @geza - Yes, someone dropped the ball there. I guess `is_pointer_to_member` wasn't catchy enough.

Comment: ...but why is `bool` the "closest one"?

Comment: @ilkkachu: a pointer-to-member only has a few implicit conversion possibilities: to `bool`, and to a "similar" pointer-to-member type. Among these, iostream only supports `bool`.

Comment: @geza, on second thought, that makes sense. It was just my internal low-level programmer thinking about automatically converting to an `int`.

Answer (score 21):

The output is different because the behavior of your `printf` is undefined.

A pointer to member (like the one produced from `&Foo::c`) is not an integer. The `printf` function expects an integer, since you told it too with the `%d` specifier.

You can amend it by adding a cast to `bool`, like this:

```
printf("%d\n", (bool)&Foo::c)
```

A pointer to member may be converted to a bool (which you do with the cast), and the `bool` then undergoes integral promotion to an `int` on account of being an integral variadic argument to a variadic function.

Speaking of the conversion to `bool`, it's exactly the conversion that is applied implicitly by attempting to call `std::ostream`'s `operator<<`. Since there isn't an overload of the operator that supports pointers to members, overload resolution selects another that is callable after implicitly converting `&Foo::c` to a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the more literal answer about why the compiler interpreted your code the way it did: you seem to have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info)   You’re trying to format a pointer-to-member as an integer, which strongly suggests you meant to do something different.

If what you wanted was an `int` value stored in `.c`, you either need to create an instance `Foo some_foo;` and take `some_foo.c`, or else you need to declare `Foo::c` a `static` member, so there’s one unambiguous `Foo::c` across the entire class.  Do not take the address in this case.

If what you wanted was to take an address of the `.c` member of some `Foo`, you should do as above so that `Foo::c` is `static` and refers to one specific variable, or else declare an instance and take its `.c` member, then take the address.  The correct `printf()` specifier for an object pointer is `%p`, and to print an object pointer representation with `<iostream>`, convert it to `void*`:

```
printf( "%p\n", &some_foo.c );
std::cout << static_cast<void*>{&some_foo.c} << '\n';
```

If what you want is the offset of `Foo::c` within class `Foo`, you want the `offsetof()` macro in `<stddef.h>`.  Since its return value is `size_t`, which is not the same size as `int` on 64-bit platforms, you would want to either cast the result explicitly or pass `printf()` the `z` type specifier:

```
#include <stddef.h>

/* ... */

  constexpr size_t offset_c = offsetof( Foo, c );
  printf( "%zu\n", offset_c );
  cout << offset_c << '\n';
```

Whatever you were trying to do, if your compiler didn’t warn you about the type mismatch, you ought to turn on more warnings.  This is especially true for someone coding by trial and error until the program compiles.